# As an Outlook administrator using custom domain name, is it possible to monitor incoming emails for the users created?

Tags: email, administrator, monitoring, outlook.com

I just created an administrator account on outlook with a custom domain name. Is it possible to monitor incoming emails for users that I created? If so, how can I do that? I don't see any option to do this. I can only create up to 50 users and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, a microsoft representative said it's not possible for now. It may be in the future.